# How can I build a function using subfunctions

Tags: functions

I am trying to build a function in Mathematica. The function is quite long so I would like to define subfunctions and then build them in the final function. Something like f1(t),f2(t),f3(t).... the gets put together in  f(t,f1(t),f2(t),f3(t))

Below is the actual code:

```
C00 = 1000*10^(-12);
CHG = 26.01*10^(-12);
CLG = 28.48*10^(-12);
Lcm = 26.7*10^(-9);
LHL = 30.04*10^(-9);
LHG = 9*10^(-9);
L00 = 0.2*10^(-9);
LLG = 7*10^(-9);
C0 := C00/(1 - t^2 + L00*C00);
CH := CHG/(1 - t^2 + LHG*CHG);
CL := CLG/(1 - t^2 LLG*CLG);
C1 := C0 + ((-t^2 *Lcm*CH*CL)/(1 - t^2 *Lcm* (CH + CL)));
LE := (1 + CH/C1)*LHL + (1 + CL/C1)*LHL;
f[t_] := (C0*(1 - t^2 *Lcm*(CH + CL + (CH*CL)/C0)))*((1 - t^2 *Lcm (CH + CL))*(1 - t^2 LE*C0) + t^4*Lcm*LE*CH*CL)^-1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You might try something like this:

```
(* Parameterise some of the delayed definitions. *)
c0[t_] := C00/(1 - t^2 + L00*C00);
cH[t_] := CHG/(1 - t^2 + LHG*CHG);
cL[t_] := CLG/(1 - t^2 LLG*CLG);
c1[t_] := c0[t] + ((-t^2 *Lcm*cH[t]*cL[t])/(1 - t^2 *Lcm* (cH[t] + cL[t])));
lE[t_] := (1 + cH[t]/c1[t])*LHL + (1 + cL[t]/c1[t])*LHL;

(* Then define some helper functions. *)
g1[t_] := (c0[t]*(1-t^2*Lcm*(cH[t]+cL[t]+(cH[t]*cL[t])/c0[t])));
g2[t_] := (1-t^2*Lcm (cH[t]+cL[t]));
g3[t_] := (1-t^2 lE[t]*c0[t]);
g4[t_] := t^4*Lcm*lE[t]*cH[t]*cL[t];

(* Now define f as follows: *)
f[t_] := g1[t] * (g2[t] * g3[t] + g4[t])^(-1);
```

<s>I have not executed any of your definitions. My answer is simply a suggestion for how you might organise some of your code.</s>

**EDIT**

Some of the inner expressions had remained unparameterised in my first answer. With the changes above, I get:

```
f[1.5]
(* -8. x (10 ^ -10) *)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I try to parametrise sub functions I get an error:c0[t_] := C00/(1 - t^2 + L00*C00)
cH[t_] := CHG/(1 - t^2 + LHG*CHG)
cL[t_] := CLG/(1 - t^2 LLG*CLG)
c1[t_] := c0 + ((-t^2 *Lcm*cH[t]*cL[t])/(1 - t^2 *Lcm*(cH[t] + cL[t])))
lE[t_] := (1 + cH[t]/c1[t])*LHL + (1 + cL[t]/c1[t])*LHL
SetDelayed::write: Tag Times in (CHG/(1+CHG LHG-t^2))[t_] is Protected.

Comment: Some of the inner expressions had not taken on the new parameterised forms. I have made the corrections. Try this version.